# Why can I write and read double-underscore variables outside a class, are they not mangled?

Tags: python

Why can the code below run?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__w = 10

s = A()
s.__w = 20
print(s.__w)  # 20
s.__haha = 1
print(s.__haha)  # 1
```

Comment: Do you think it shouldn't run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in fact not read `s.__w` outside the class before you assign `s.__w = 20`.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__w = 10

s = A()
print(s.__w)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mangle.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(s.__w)
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '__w'
```

By assigning to `s.__w` from outside the class, you create a *separate* variable which is not mangled (it's separate because the original variable *is* mangled):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__w = 10

s = A()
s.__w = 20
print(vars(s))
```

```
{'_A__w': 10, '__w': 20}
```

Name mangling occurs only within a class definition: [Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers)